# Finding the length of sub-string using regular expression

Tags: c#

I have managed to match the groups as follows using the expression,

`\([^\)]*\)`

Example strings are,

s11(h 1 1 c)(h 1 1 c) x="" y="" z="" phi="" theta=""

e(45,10,h 1 1 c,1,cross,max) x="" y="" z="" phi="" theta=""

With the above expression I can match `(h 1 1 c)(h 1 1 c)` and `(45,10,h 1 1 c,1,cross,max)`

But I want to capture the starting string `s11` and `e` along with `(h 1 1 c)(h 1 1 c)` and `(45,10,h 1 1 c,1,cross,max)`

Comment: why a regex at all? What did you even try? We´re not here to give you the ready to copy code. If regex is not your strenght, it´s a good point to start learning it.

Comment: Don't use Regex for this. It's a one-liner: [indexof](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking for length until first occurence is the same as asking of index of first occurence.

No need for regular expressions here, as stated in comments, method returning index of first occurence will suffice:

```
var lengthOfSubstring = "rxx(a 0 0 b)(a 0 0 b)".IndexOf(')'); // returns 11
if( lengthOfSubstring < 0 )
{
    // character not found within the string, so the substring doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Note: `IndexOf` is zero-based (as all things should be), but since OP want's the "length of the substring **until** (not _including_) the first `)`", that's exactly that. Also: if `IndexOf` returns a negative value (`-1`) it means that the search character does not occur in the string at all. So it might be worth keeping an eye out for that.